# Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $T \in \mathscr{L}(V)$ is such that every nonzero vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of identity operator.

My question is about why the certain statements we prove leads to the conclusion of the question.

After attempting the problem and not getting the correct solution. I found a solution online that stated the following:

> To show $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity, we must show that $a_v$ is independent of $v$ for $v\in V\setminus\{{0}\}$.
>   Suppose $v,w \in V\setminus\{{0}\}$ We want to show $a_v = a_w$

When I attempted the problem I was under the impression that seeing that every vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ It would simply follow that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity since:  $$T(v) = \lambda v = \lambda I(v)$$

So why is it that these two conditions show that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity?

**Note:** I know how to do the mechanics of the problem already. It is the reasoning I am having problems with.

Comment: Every nonzero vector is an eigenvector, but you don't know (without proving it) that they correspond to the _same_ eigenvalue. In other words, the constant $\lambda$ potentially depends on the choice of $v$.

Comment: What you know is $\forall v\in V, \exists \lambda_v \in k$ such that $T(v)=\lambda_v v$. What you want is $\exists \lambda \in k$ such that $\forall v\in V, T(v)=\lambda v$.

Comment: Take two linearly independent vectors $u,v$, and their sum $u+v$, with eigenvalues $r,s,t$ respectively. Then $t(u+v)=T(u+w)=T(u)+T(w)=ru+sv$. Use that they are linearly independent and that any two pairs of vectors are either linearly independent or not, and when they are not, they also belong to the same eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything being an eigenvector implies that there is only one eigenvalue:$av=Tv=T\sum v_i=\sum a_iv_i $ where $v_i$ are basis vectors and $a_i $ the corresponding eigenvalues.
So $av=av_1+\dots +av_n=a_1v_1+\dots +a_nv_n$, hence $a=a_i$ for all $i $.

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec v \ne 0 \ne \vec w$ are linearly *dependent*, they are in fact collinear and there is some scalar $\alpha \ne 0$ with

$w = \alpha v; \tag 1$

letting $\mu_{\vec v}$ be the eigenvalue associated with vector $\vec v$, so that

$T\vec v = \mu_{\vec v} \vec v, \tag 2$

we have

$T\vec w = T(\alpha \vec v) = \alpha T \vec v = \alpha \mu_{\vec v} \vec v = \mu_{\vec v} (\alpha \vec v) = \mu_{\vec v} \vec w, \tag 3$

which shows that $\mu_{\vec v}$ is also an eigenvalue for $\vec w$, that is

$\mu_{\vec w} = \mu_{\vec v}; \tag 4$

the eigenvalues are the same in the case (1).

Now suppose $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are *not* collinear, i.e, they are linearly independent, then

$\mu_{\vec v + \vec w} \vec v + \mu_{\vec v + \vec w} \vec w = \mu_{\vec v + \vec w} (\vec v + \vec w) = T(\vec v + \vec w) = T\vec v + T\vec w = \mu_{\vec v} \vec v + \mu_{\vec w} \vec w; \tag 5$

since $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are linearly indendent this implies

$\mu_{\vec v + \vec w} = \mu_{\vec v} = \mu_{\vec w}, \tag 6$

which shows that any two linearly independent eigenvectors share the same eigenvalue; this there is but one eigenvalue $\mu$ shared by all non-zeero vectors, collinear or not; then we have

$T \vec v = \mu \vec v, \; \forall \vec v, \tag 7$

and $T = \mu I$ is thus a multiple of the identity mapping.